# How to number subsections in Pages on Mac

Tags: text-editors, iwork-pages

I'm having an issue with Pages. I'm writing a document with several subsections. The problem is that when I'm using the style (ex: Subsection 2, Subsection 3...), I can't find how to add an index to it (1, 1.1, 1.2...).

Could someone explain to me how to do it?

Comment: Does [this answer][1] from superuser help?


  [1]: http://superuser.com/questions/10850/how-to-make-numbered-chapter-titles-and-paragraph-headers-in-iwork-pages-09

Comment: It's not. I just find out how to do it. I'll explain it in an answer to help some other people having the same problem.

Comment: As I can't answer my own question for now here is the solution :

You just have to enable the "Chips and lists" option and make this list and ordered list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found the answer. I just had to enable the "Chips and lists" option and make this list an ordered list.